# Examples of groups with a positive homogeneous presentation without the Haagerup property or not of type $F_\infty$

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

I am looking for groups with a certain presentation that do not have the Haagerup property or are finitely presented but not of type $F_\infty$ (meaninig that for some $n\geq 3$ we cannot find any classifying space with finite n-skeleton). The motivation comes from forest-skein groups ([arXiv:2207.03100](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03100) and [arXiv:2212.01993](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.01993)) and finding some without the two properties cited above (question that I can reduce to monoids).

Here is the precise question.
Assume you have a presented monoid $M$ where all the relations are of the form $w=w'$ where $w,w'$ are words of the same length.
For instance, $\langle a,b\mid ab = ba,aa = bb\rangle$.

Now further assume the following:

a) $M$ is left-cancellative (if $xy=xz$, then $y=z$)

b) $M$ has common right-multiples (for any $x,y$ in $M$, there exists $u,v$ in $M$ such that $xu = yv$).

This allows you to form the fraction group $G$ of the monoid $M$ where all elements of $G$ can be written as $x y^{-1}$ for some $x,y$ in $M$.
The group $G$ has the same presentation than $M$ (so in particular it has a positive homogeneous group presentation).
Examples of such $G$ are Thompson's group $F$, the braid groups, etc.

My questions are:

1. Can you find such a $G$ that does not have the Haagerup property?
2. Can you find such a $G$ which admits a finite presentation but is not of type $F_\infty$?

For 1), it is sufficient to find a fraction group $G$ as above with an infinite subset $X$ so that the pair $(G,X)$ has the relative Kazhdan property (T). Note that the whole group $G$ cannot have Kazhdan property (T) since it surjects onto the infinite cyclic group via the word-length map. Further note that (as far as I am aware of) the braid groups $B_n$ are not known to have the Haageurp property (but they may all have it).

For 2), I am lacking examples of finitely presented groups not of type $F_\infty$. Any possible family that could possibly be deformed into what I precisely want would be nice.

Comment: I think you need cancellative not just left cancellative

Comment: For 2), candidates to look at might be Houghton groups and lamplighter groups of higher rank.

Comment: For 2) do you want the group to be a group of fractions of a homogeneous monoid?

Comment: The first example of a finitely presented group not of type $F_\infty$ is Stallings' group: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373106 . Stallings gives an explicit and fairly short presentation, so you could see if you can massage it into the form you want.

Comment: @HJRW, I'm pretty sure that it is not of this form.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think the Stallings group does at least admit a finite "balanced" presentation. Just replace the relation Axc=cAx with (a new generator d and) the relations xc=dx and ac=da, and similarly for the other two unbalanced defining relations, so you end up with 8 generators and 10 defining relations. I have no idea whether the resulting finite balanced presentation satisfies these monoid properties though.

Comment: @MattZaremsky, I thought Stallings example is not an ore condition monoid because of how it sits in a direct product of free groups but maybe this is not the example I was thinking of

Comment: @MattZaremsky, I believe that if it's not ore.  You can't find anything in aM\cap bM in your presentation where M is the monoid with your presentation.

Comment: @MattZaremsky   Also I think you may need the new generator d =acA and the relations da=ac, db=bc, dx=xc,dy=yc

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Oh yeah you only need d, not "e" and "f" too. So probably you can get away with 6 generators and 8 relations. But I think you're right that a and b have no common right multiple, so this doesn't work anyway. Maybe something less beholden to free groups would be better, like Genevois's suggestions above.

Comment: There's a concrete finite presentation (3 generators, 5 relations) for the third Houghton group (which is not of type F_3) in Theorem 2.8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0257.pdf, if anyone feels like trying to finagle that into a finite, positive, balanced presentation whose corresponding monoid has the Ore property (seems hard).

Comment: It might be worth keeping in mind if M is a cancellative Ore monoid of type FP_infinity then so is its group of fractions. If the monoid is cycle free in the sense of adjan or has a complete rewriting system its FP_infinity

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: you need that M is cancellative if you want that it embedds in its fraction group. I actually don't need that and only want a left-cancellative monoid. For you other question: yes for both questions (1 and 2) I want a group G equal to a fraction group of a homogeneously presented monoid (the conditions a and b that I have written down).

Comment: If you don't want M to embed in G then you don't even need left cancellative for each element of G to be of the form $xy^{-1}$ with $x,y$ in the image of $M$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I am using the calculus of fractions as described in the book of Gabriel and Zisman [link](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/GZ.pdf). I could weaken b) into weak-left-cancellative as follows: (xy=xz implies that there exists w so that yw=zw) although for mysterious reasons I want it. I assume there are other ways to obtain a calculus of fractions but outside of axioms a) and b) (or week-b)) I don't know how to do it, (how works the multiplication, and how the monoid presentation is converted into a group presentation).

Comment: The calculus of fractions makes things nicer in terms of when two fractions are equal but the group with the same presentation as the monoid has the existence of fractions if you see $x^{-1}y$ with x,y generators and xu=yv in the monoid, then in the group $x^{-1}y=uv^{-1}$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg What’s the reference for that Adian cycle-free monoids are are $FP_\infty$?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda They are aspherical by Ivanov/Remmer and so the augmented Cayley complex gives a resolution of the trivial module by a result of Pride.  You can find the reference in my Lyndon identity paper with Bob. I'm assuming finite cycle free presentation